# Duality in a monoidal category as a functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

In a [rigid monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_category) $\mathcal{M}$ every object has a (say left) dual. Is the process of taking duals functorial? More specifically - is there a well-defined functor
$$
\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}^{\mathrm{op}}, ~~~ X \mapsto X^*.
$$
If so how does it act on morphisms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is covered in [Davydov, A. A. (1998). "Monoidal categories and functors". Journal of Mathematical Sciences. 88 (4): 458–472](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02365309), which is linked from the wikipedia page on rigid categories. The functoriality of taking the dual is discussed on the very first page. To better understand what this functor does on morphisms, see Proposition 6.1.

Comment: Maybe it is worth clarifying that this is contravariant functoriality as the question seems to be asking for a covariant functoriality. In most concrete exemple (like finite dimensional vector spaces) one can show there is no covariant functoriality.

Comment: Oh, yes, I agree with that. I didn't see that the OP wrote $M \to M$ and no $op$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the "op". I have edited it.